# For symmetry of wave function global phase is not allowed?

Tags: condensed-matter, symmetry, topological-phase

The key equation leading to the group cohomology classification of SPT phases is equation 12 on pp.8 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.4772) which I reproduce below

$$ \bigotimes_i{U^i}|\Psi_{pSRE}\rangle = |\Psi_{pSRE}\rangle $$

which states mathematically that the wave function is invariant under the onsite transformation of its symmetry group.

But we all know that adding a global phase to a wave function does not alter the physical state it describes.  Thus my question is: is this the ad hoc definition of wave function symmetry adopted by the paper or in general when we talk about the symmetry of a wave function we do not allow extra global phase albeit it does not change the corresponding physical state.

Comment: At least in the arxiv version, eq. 12 does not appear as the starting point, but as a consequence of the form of states they consider.  Could you clarify this aspect of your question?  (Also, it would be better to link to the arxiv version.)

Comment: @NorbertSchuch: the link is corrected to the arXiv version. Thanks for the suggestion! On the other hand I am actually just asking in general whether the symmetry of a wave function allows nontrivial global phase or not.

Comment: In principle yes.  Of course, if U is, say, a representation of SU(2), then there cannot be a non-trivial phase, because $\Psi$ forms a 1D irrep, and the only 1D irrep of SU(2) is trivial.  On the other hand, such a phase is typically not relevant for the classification (you can e.g. think of simple cases where the phase depends on the system size).

Comment: @NorbertSchuch: many thanks for the clarification!  It seems like you are arguing that whether a global phase is allowed without affecting the classification depends on the specific symmetry group and the specific model thus there is not a general answer.  Am I right?

Comment: Not really. One thing I am saying is that for certain symmetry groups (such as SU(2)) there cannot be a nontrivial such phase.  Second, I'm indeed saying that this phase typically does not matter for the classification (as I understand it).

Comment: @NorbertSchuch: Many thanks!  Would you mind consolidating a bit your comments into an answer so that I can give you more credit for answering my question?

Comment: I'll try -- though I feel that in this case I should add at least a bit more substance to the answer.